# For loop, keep variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

Let's say I have the current code:

```
for(var n = 0; n != 5;n++){
  alert(i);
}
```

It will alert 0,1,2,3,4

Though now let's say I need to execute an asynchronous function that has a return function you can pass as a parameter.

```
for(var n = 0; n != 5;n++){
  doAsync(function(){alert(n);});
}

function doAsync(func){
  setTimeout(func, 1000);
}
```

This will alert "5", 5 times. Is there a way I can have the n variable stay the same as it was in the loop? By this I mean I'd like it to execute 0,1,2,3,4.

Thanks, I appreciate all help.

Comment: Use a closure inside of `for` loop or substitute `.map()` and `Promise.all()` for `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical closure problem.

you can change your code as the following

```js
for (var n = 0; n != 5; n++) {
  alert(n);
}


for (var n = 0; n != 5; n++) {
  doAsync(function(n) {
    alert(n);
  }.bind(null,n));
}

function doAsync(func) {
  setTimeout(func, 1000);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

```js
for (var n = 0; n != 5; n++) {
  (function(x) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(x);
    }, 1000);
  })(n);
}
```

Option 2:

```js
for (var n = 0; n != 5; n++) {
  (function(x) {
    doAsync(function() {
      alert(x);
    });
  })(n);
}

function doAsync(func) {
  setTimeout(func, 1000);
}
```